# Using curl to send mail from gmail

Tags: php, curl, gmail

Is it possible to login to my gmail account and send mail using curl in php? I don't want to use pop3 or any other function.

```
$msg = "something";
$email = "sa@sas.com";
$pass= "something"

function send($msg, $email, $pass)
{
//something
}
```

I have never used curl, to be honest. Have just heard of it.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to use an undocumented, unsupported HTTP non-API when they support SMTP?

Comment: Uh, cURL isn't designed for email...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is theoretically possible, but extremely complex and subject to breaking whenever Google decide to change their HTML interface. Not a good idea.

Your best option is to use Google Mails's SMTP servers. Mailer packages like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) make this easy to set up.

[Here](http://www.swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/connections/smtp) is an example for how to connect to GMail with SMTP.

Answer (score 2):

You may do it with libcurl without many troubles. Here is an example http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-tls.html of how to send email using TLS (all you need to send via gmail) in C. I believe libcurl PHP port provides the same ability.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible but the codebase would be huge and the benefits very small compared with using imap or pop3 or other services.

Why  do you want to do this?

p.s. gmail has a limit on the numbers of email you cand send per hour, as far as i know. So, if you're trying to use gmail to send mass emails i would advise against it.

Answer (score 0):

I should use SMTP for it, there are some great mailer classes for SMTP (E.g. Zend_Mail). Zend components can be use stand alone and are very great.

Answer (score 0):

Libcurl is designed to support smtp email since version 7.20 (April 2010). It also support several authentication methods (SSL, TLS, CRAM-MD5)